# How can i add image icon on listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I am having a listview where items are coming from database. I tried to putting image icon for listview item in xml. but, it's not showing the icon.i tried many things but nothing seems to work on this?

Here is my Listview :

```
public class TypeMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = TypeMenu.class.getSimpleName();
    String bid;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    private static final String TAG_BID = "bid";

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://cloud....com/brtemp/index.php";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();


        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem

                HashMap<String, String> selected = contactList.get(position);
                String selectedId= selected.get("id");
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubMenu.class);
                //  sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra("id",selectedId);
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast" +selectedId ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TypeMenu.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
         String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);





            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArry = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArry.length(); i++)
                    {

                        JSONObject c = jsonArry.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String type = c.getString("type");
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                       contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("type", type);
                        contactList.add(contact);


                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    TypeMenu.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "type","id"},
                    new int[]{
                    R.id.type,R.id.arrow1});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
        }
```

above code if i put   " R.id.Type, R.id.arrow1" then list lis not opening and giving me error.

here is my Listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

here is my logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.zeba.broccoli, PID: 1231
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2452)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                      at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
                      at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleAdapter.java:262)
                      at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:192)
                      at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
                      at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1292)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1204)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:768)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5908)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3076)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18870)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2392)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1416)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1661)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7016)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventRec
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1231 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: What is the error? You have to know, that Error of any sort, is like an output function of certain algorithm. If we know the output, we may have greater chance to write a better algorithm based on output AKA if we know your error, we don't need to scan your entire code to first identify the error, and then start to waste time for investigating the issue.

Comment: if i try put R.id.arrow1 there ..then its showing me tht error

Comment: The error is telling you that he cannot find the resource. So check for typos or make sure you are looking at the right Resources.

Comment: i have already put my code above ..and i just to show type and arrow(image) i dont know whr i m wrong

Comment: Well I only see "Resource Not Found Exception", but I cannot really see at which line. So maybe check, which Resource Android Studio cannot find.

Comment: i am getting error online where i am putting R.id.arrow1...plz see my updated ques

Comment: even after doing debugging nothin is happening ...

Comment: i cants see why the icon image is not coming on listview

Answer (score 1):

You are only loading two TextViews in your Adapter.

```
new String[]{ "type","id"}
```

So the IDs should  be those TextViews only. Primarily because I don't think SimpleAdapter can load ImageViews from the data collection of a Hashmap of String,String.

So, instead of

```
R.id.type,R.id.arrow1
```

You need to not use the ImageView

```
R.id.type,R.id.id
```

Comment: need to or i dont need to ...wht shud i do with my code to get image icon

Comment: i am not getting u properly